# Error establishing a database connection: Google App Engine Deploy

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am running **2nd** generation instance.
I am able to connect locally but when I run `gcloud app deploy` I keep getting the error **Error establishing a database connection**
I have tried using `root` and a blank password and still does not work.

I have followed instructions from https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible and still getting the error.

See my wp-config.php page as well as the screenshot from cloud.google.com everything matches but still getting the error.

[image: Local Connection of SQL Working]

[image: My Instance]

[image: My Users]

[image: wp-config.php][image: SQL Instance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible
) you mentioned and got the same issue. When I followed instructions on GitHub of [the sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples) it works as expected.

An important difference I found is that the official tutorial doesn't mention cron.yaml:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

and in the repo:

```
gcloud app deploy \
    --promote --stop-previous-version app.yaml cron.yaml
```

I would follow the github version only.

Comment: The issue was caused by Wordpress 4.9 after updating to 4.9.1 it worked. Much appreciated